# About Uploading multiple files and giving the filename to fileupload control programatically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

My client has one requirement.

He wants to upload all the text files from folder "D:/MyFolder/" by clicking on a button.

So I tried It but I am having the problems.

Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub btnAutoUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAutoUpload.Click

    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    'Connecting and retrieving data form Database.
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = '" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Data.accdb") & "'"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblUserDetails WHERE UserType = 'Company'"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, con)
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "tblUserDetails")

    Dim fileUploadPath As String = "C:/MUNIM/"

    Dim NumberOfFilesToUpload As Integer = FileCount(fileUploadPath)

    Dim Extension As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Dim files() As String
    files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(fileUploadPath)

    For x As Integer = 0 To NumberOfFilesToUpload - 1

        Extension = IO.Path.GetExtension(files(x))

        If Extension = ".txt" Then

            fileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files(x))

            If fileName = ds.Tables("tblUserDetails").Rows(x).Item("FileName") Then

                'Count the no. of document uploaders
                Dim lineCount = IO.File.ReadAllLines(documentViewersPath).Length

                'reading the names of document uploaders
                Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(documentViewersPath)
                Dim allLines As New List(Of String)
                Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
                    allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
                Loop
                reader.Close()

                For i As Integer = 0 To lineCount - 1

                    If ds.Tables("tblUserDetails").Rows(x).Item("UserName") = ReadLine(i, allLines) Then

                        'Save the file to desired location (Upload File)

                    End If

                Next

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

How is this possible?

Should I use FileUpload Control?

If yes, then How can I select specific folder to upload files from?

Or How should I give Filename to FileUpload Control Programatically? as it is readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant really have your server just grab files off a clients machine legitimately.  This is what the file upload control is for. Generally the client initiates the upload.

You can use file upload control with multiple attribute to allow you to select multiple files in IE version 10+ , FF, Chrome, Opera. Otherwise, without the multiple attribute it is tedious to upload files since you can't shift / control click all files.

You will save the file's in the [httpfilecollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection.aspx) and simply loop through and use the .SaveAs property to save to your destination file.  I can provide same code if you need..

```
Asp

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" multiple runat="server" />


<br />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click" 
    Height="26px" />
```

**c#** You or someone please convert, I have not done vb in ages :P

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i != hfc.Count; i++ )
    {
        hfc[i].SaveAs(@"D:\MyFolder\" + hfc[i].FileName);
    }

}
```

In production , this would require your server to have folder rights.

Comment: I have tried to use your code as you suggested but I am not able to select multiple files. In fact first I got the warning that multiple should be followed by = sign. So I changed it to multiple = "true". But still I am not able to select multiple files.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you good sir, I just re copied back in the code and I can shift + multiple files into the upload control.